# How to logout from Salesforce remote hybrid app

Tags: hybrid-remote

how to implement logout functionality in remote hybrid  app using logout button ?
my button show alert message but not logout the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SalesforceSDK you can write custom method to logout

```
function logout(){

  var sfOAuthPlugin  = cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.oauth");
  sfOAuthPlugin.logout();
}
```

This method logouts current user.It will securly loggedout the user and flush the stored access and refresh token